# what is best way to put js array into extjs scrollable menu

Tags: javascript, extjs

Instead of "Item 1" etc, I'd like to put my own data into the scrollable menu dropdown in extjs and then send the value to query the appropriate page. Here's the documentation on extjs menu:

```
var scrollMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i){ // replace this loop with one that loops thru my data
        scrollMenu.add({
            text: 'Item ' + (i + 1), // replace this with text from array (see my data below)
            id: // replace this with number from array (see my data below)
        });
    }
    // scrollable menu
    tb.add({
        icon: 'preview.png',
        cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
        text: 'Scrolling Menu',
        menu: scrollMenu
    });
```

[View an online sample](http://ngs.woc.noaa.gov/storms/scripts/ext-3.2.1/examples/menu/menus.html) and click the "Scrolling Menu" button in the menu.

This is my data:

```
var locations = [
    [23, 'Main Room'],
    [1, 'Main Lobby'],
    [2, 'Training Room'],
    [56, 'Main Office'],
    [57, 'Lower Office'],
    [9, 'Lower Lobby'],
    [62, 'Conference Room'],
    [22, 'Outdoor Patio'],
    [63, 'Upper Lobby']
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working!

```
var scrollMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu();
    Ext.each(locations, function (name, index, locationsItSelf) {

        scrollMenu.add({
           // text: 'Item ' + (i + 1)
            value: name[0],
            text: name[1]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same process. Loop over it to transform it into an array of objects.

```
var items = [];

Ext.Array.forEach(locations, function(item) {
    items.push({
        id: 'item' + item[0],
        text: item[1]
    });
});

new Ext.menu.Menu({
    items: items
});
```

Comment: I'm not having any luck with that suggestion. I added a comma after item[0] and added "var scrollMenu =" in front of new Ext.menu.Menu({